# ArcObjects: AfterItemDraw only fires for layers in the root of TOC

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcmap

As I mentioned at the end of [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/22215/753) the [`IActiveViewEvents.AfterItemDraw`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AfterItemDraw_Event/00120000019q000000/) event (even with [`IViewManager.VerboseEvents`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000rt5000000) enabled) only seems to fire for layers in the root of ArcMap's table of contents, not nested sublayers, so if you want individual events to be fired for a layer it must be moved into the root of the TOC and not within a group layer.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this or have findings to the contrary?

Comment: Is your goal still the same - to get performance stats?

Comment: Yeah; what I've done in the linked answer is working well except that it only works on root layers.